# WP8.1 Listpicker throws (Error HRESULT E_Fail has been returned from a call to a COM component)

Tags: windows-phone-8, wptoolkit

1. Windows Phone Databound project targeting WP 8.1 OS.
2. Added WPToolkit through NuGet
3. Added toolkit reference to the page:

   xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
4. Added a list picker and gave it items source.

When I deploy to the phone it is working just fine. But in the designer I get this error, and it's pretty annoying, I was wondering if I can do something about it?

[image]

UPDATE:

Restarting visual studio solved the problem.

Comment: E_FAIL is just a teacher's grade for the quality of the error reporting, it is meaningless to diagnose what really went wrong.  Trouble-shooting it is pretty painful, involving lots of trial and an error that won't go away.  The odds that you'll find somebody here willing to do this for you are proportional to how easy you make it to get a repro.  Which right now are very close to zero with just a lazy screenshot to look at.  You'll have to do the [legwork first](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @HansPassant You are right. But I've been trying to figure out what's wrong for two hours now. I've searched SOF and the web, with no luck. I'm sorry that you called it a lazy screenshot, God knows I tried. The setup is as I described, and there is no code but initiating a list and setting it to the list picker source. Please let me know if there is anything else I can add.

Comment: @Idrees probably need to post full XAML.

Comment: It is just a new windows phone databound project. There is nothing really in the XAML. Anyway, I've restarted visual studio and the error went away. Cannot answer my own question for another 2 days...